# Put intervals from functions together

Tags: matlab, geometry

I have these functions and want to put them together in one window (with the plot function), so that a composite and smooth function is generated.

```
x1 = linspace(0, 0.5, 1000);
y1 = coordinates(1)*x1.^3 + coordinates(2)*x1.^2 + coordinates(3)*x1 + coordinates(4);

x2 = linspace(0.5, 1, 1000);
y2 = coordinates(5)*x2.^3 + coordinates(6)*x2.^2 + coordinates(7)*x2 + coordinates(8);

x3 = linspace(1, 6, 1000);
y3 = coordinates(9)*x3.^3 + coordinates(10)*x3.^2 + coordinates(11)*x3 + coordinates(12);

x4 = linspace(6, 7, 1000);
y4 = coordinates(13)*x4.^3 + coordinates(14)*x4.^2 + coordinates(15)*x4 + coordinates(16);

x5 = linspace(7, 9 ,1000);
y5 = coordinates(17)*x5.^3 + coordinates(18)*x5.^2 + coordinates(19)*x5 + coordinates(20);
```

As you can see I have some values saved in coordinates. You don't need this values. I just want to know how I can generally put parts with the plot function together in one window. Like in the following image (example with GeoGebra) I want to put the single functions in an intervall together and receive one function:
[image]

Comment: You can use with [plot](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#bt2458m)

Comment: I know but I don't know how exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `plot` function specifying all the data set you want to plot.

In the call to `plot` you can also specify the color of each segment.

You can use the [text](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function to add some text / label on the plot.

As an example for three set of data `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y2)` and `(x3, y3)`

```
figure

x1 = linspace(0, 0.5, 1000);
y1 = x1.^2;

x2 = linspace(0.5, 1, 1000);
y2 = x2.^2;

x3 = linspace(1, 2, 1000);
y3 = x3.^2;

plot(x1,y1,'r',x2,y2,'g',x3,y3,'b','linewidth',2)
hold on
text(x1(3),y1(3),'A')
text(x2(3),y2(3),'B')
text(x3(3),y3(3),'C')

grid minor
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: I've updated the example by adding the code to add some text / label on the figure.